# Как разбить строку при помощи регулярных выражений (java)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, arraylist

Пишу мой первый калькулятор. Хочу разбить строку из цифр и знаков на 2 коллекции.
Ввожу следующий код:

```
protected static String Go (String s) {    
  ArrayList <String> Numbers = new ArrayList <String> ();
  ArrayList <String> Simbols = new ArrayList <String> ();     

  for (String c1 : s.split("[^0-9]+"))
    Numbers.add(c1);

  for (String c2 : s.split("[0-9]+"))
    Simbols.add(c2);
```

При тестировании выдает самые разные результаты, например:

1. `s="6-6"` получаю:

   ```
   Numbers=[6, 6]
   Simbols=[, -]
   ```
2. `s="+6+6"` получаю:

   ```
   Numbers=[, 6, 6]
   Simbols=[+, +]
   ```
3. `s="+6+6"` получаю:

   ```
   Numbers=[, 6, 6]
   Simbols=[+, +]
   ```

Т. е. в начало коллекции Simbols или Numbers почему-то ставится пустой элемент.
Из-за этого ничего дальше не могу сделать.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` слишком ограниченный даже для простого калькулятора. Я бы предложил использовать регулярные выражения с именованными группами. Можно будет удобно парсить строку.

Вот неплохая статья по вашей задаче: [Однострочный калькулятор, искусство или порок?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320830/)

Дополнительные ссылки:

[Обработка строк в Java. Часть II: Pattern, Matcher](https://habrahabr.ru/post/260773/)

[Pattern. Возможности для описания регулярных выражений](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/7/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Т.е. В начало коллекции Simbols или Numbers почему-то ставится пустой элемент.

Потому что строка начинается либо с цифры, либо с не цифры. И этот символ послужит частью разделителя в одном из разбиений. Ну а что находится между ним и началом строки? Пустая строка - вот она и отправляется в один из результатов.

PS: А калькулятор так всё равно не получится: `+6+-7`. Разбивай на токены-строки и потом уже их поштучно обрабатывай.

Answer (score 1):

Если не трогать регулярные вырожения, можно реализовать через [обратную польскую запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C), пример [из моего репозитория](https://github.com/iagulevich/IntervaleCalculate)